# Is there any way to exclude blank cells in rows

Tags: excel

I have the Excel sheet with the blank cells in the rows. But I want that to be without blank cells in the rows.

Ex.

```
James|23-jul-18|24-jul-18|25-jul-18|      |       |      |03-aug-18
```

To

```
James|23-jul-18|24-jul-18|25-jul-18 |03-aug-
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Likewise for n number of rows

Comment: Your question is a little confusing. Are you trying to import this data, or is it already in a spreadsheet?

Comment: Select the rows containing your data -> Press `F5` to open the GoTo window -> Click the `Special...` button in the lower left -> Select `Blanks` -> Click OK -> Now only the blank cells are currently selected -> Right-click any of the blank cells -> Click `Delete` from the right-click menu -> Select `Shift cells left` -> Click OK

Comment: really confusing what the question is here. Are these values within 1 cell or do you mean to indicate different cells with | ? 
And how is this consistent (or not) over the rows?

Comment: Yes .I just used "|" to differentiate the cells

Comment: Here the problem is the empty cells contain formula so the way of excluding blanks using special--> blanks not working

Comment: Here is a solution I found off site.

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4595-excel-delete-blank-cells-and-move-left.html

Comment: I guess your formula needs changing to check if the result would be blank and if it is look at the next date, etc.  Without sample data and the formula you're using I couldn't hazard a guess at what needs changing.

Comment: What do you mean when you say *exclude blank cells in rows*? Why can you just delete those blank columns?

Comment: If the blanks are the result of formulas, then have the formulas use `NA()` instead of `""` so that instead of blanks you end up with `#N/A` errors.  Then you can use the same steps I provided previously, except instead of GoTo -> Special -> Blanks it would be GoTo -> Special -> Formulas -> Uncheck everything except `Errors`

Comment: Otherwise this will require VBA.

Answer (score 0):

For a macro that will do this automatically for you and will catch blanks that are actually blank in addition to blanks that are the result of formulas:

```
Sub DeleteBlanks()

    Dim rSearch As Range
    Dim rFound As Range
    Dim rDel As Range
    Dim sFirst As String
    Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long

    'Get search range, have user select rows
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rSearch = Application.InputBox("Select the rows to delete blanks", "Delete Blank Range Selection", Selection.Address, Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If rSearch Is Nothing Then Exit Sub 'Pressed cancel

    'Limit search range to only populated area
    Set rFound = rSearch.Find("*", rSearch.Cells(1), xlValues, xlPart, xlByRows, xlPrevious)
    If Not rFound Is Nothing Then LastRow = rFound.Row Else LastRow = rSearch.Row + rSearch.Rows.Count - 1
    Set rFound = rSearch.Find("*", rSearch.Cells(1), xlValues, xlPart, xlByColumns, xlPrevious)
    If Not rFound Is Nothing Then LastCol = rFound.Column Else LastCol = rSearch.Column + rSearch.Columns.Count - 1
    Set rSearch = rSearch.Parent.Range(rSearch.Cells(1), rSearch.Parent.Cells(LastRow, LastCol))

    'Search for blanks
    Set rFound = rSearch.Find("", rSearch.Cells(rSearch.Cells.Count), xlValues, xlWhole, , xlNext)
    If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
        sFirst = rFound.Address
        Do
            If Not rDel Is Nothing Then Set rDel = Union(rDel, rFound) Else Set rDel = rFound
            Set rFound = rSearch.FindNext(rFound)
        Loop While sFirst <> rFound.Address
    End If

    'Delete all blanks found, shifting cells to left
    If Not rDel Is Nothing Then rDel.Delete xlShiftToLeft

End Sub
```

How to use a macro:

1. Make a copy of the workbook the macro will be run on

   - Always run new code on a workbook copy, just in case the code doesn't run smoothly
   - This is especially true of any code that deletes anything
2. In the copied workbook, press ALT+F11 to open the Visual Basic Editor
3. Insert | Module
4. Copy the provided code and paste into the module
5. Close the Visual Basic Editor
6. In Excel, press ALT+F8 to bring up the list of available macros to run
7. Double-click the desired macro (I named this one DeleteBlanks)